# Vim html wrong indent

Tags: html, vim

I'm using the default indent file for html in Vim 8.0

It indents most tags well.

However, when using tags including `<script>` and `<style>`, it goes wrong.

It just look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            ...
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
button
{
    background-color: #3399ff;
}
        </style>
    </head>
...
```

And the `<script>` tag looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            ...
        </title>
    <script>
var a = "hello"; 
    </script>
    </head>
...
```

Any idea how to correctly indent them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `filetype indent on` set in your `vimrc`?  If not, please set and try and let us know the result

Comment: @dlmeetei Yes, it is already set. And the link in the first comment has solved my problem through a plugin.

Comment: That's great.  Could you summarize the reason why it is  happening for my education.

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand why it is happening.